# Python game library

Tags: python

Requirements: (most important to least important)

- Pygame-like main loop
- Windows support
- Python 3.8 support
- MinGW compiler support (if needed)
- Object classes (sprite, image, etc.)

---

*Recently, I have been trying to port an old python game written in python 2.7 into a newer version of python (3.8).
The game uses [pysfml](https://github.com/intjelic/python-sfml), which hasn't been updated for a long time, and I have yet to get it to build or install on windows.
Are there any alternatives to pysfml that work similarly? I'm looking for alternatives that will cause me to rewrite as little code as possible.*

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details, then **[edit]** your post accordingly. Especially for those not knowing the abandoned pysfml it's hard to tell what you are looking for ;) Thanks!

Comment: To improve findability, please write the question for people who have never heard of pysfml. For instance, `Similar main loop` is not clear. Thanks!